# Prove the sum of symmetric and non-symmetric matrix is $M^R_{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that:

$M^R_{2\times2} = \{A \in M^R_{2\times2} | A^t = A\} \oplus \{A \in M^R_{2\times2} | A^t = -A\}$

Well, it's pretty obvious that I need to show that the sum of symmetric and non-symmetric matrices is zero, and also the sum of their dimensions is 4. Well, it is pretty obvious it is true. Any chance you guys can help me out and solve it? If it is a duplicate, which I believe it is, I'd love to be referred to that question.

Comment: "antisymmetric"

Comment: What can you say about $A+A^t$ and $A-A^t$?

Comment: @EricTowers If u put it like that ${A + A^t \over 2} + { A - A^t \over 2} = A$, then it makes sense to me.

Comment: But I think I'll need a more general proof for that question. I mean, I'll need to show that there's $a_{ii}$ for the diag of the symmetric matrix A, then another $a_{ij} = a_{aji}$ for everything not in the diagonal. then, I will need for the antisymmetric matrix, $a_{ij} = a_{-aji}$. I will need to sum all of that somehow - generally, and then show that the sum gets me $M^R_{2\times 2}$

Comment: for the direct product you have to show that 1.) every element of the LHS can Be writen as sum of elements from RHS you have already found the solution to that in one of the comments. 2.) the intersection of the sets on the RHS must be ${0_{2\times2}}$. What does it mean that a matrix is both Simetric and Antismetric? $A^T=-A \& A^T=A\implies ???$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Each of $M_S = \{ A \in M_{2\times 2} | A = A^T\}$ and $M_{A} = \{A \in M_{2\times 2} | A = -A^T\}$ is a subspace: 
(i) $0 \in M_S \cap M_A$, where $0$ is the $2\times 2$ 0 matrix; 
(ii) $A \in M_S$ implies $(cA)^T = c A^T = cA$, so $cA \in M_S$ (ditto for $M_A$)
(iii) $A, B \in M_S$ implies $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T = A + B$, so $A+B \in M_S$ (ditto for $M_A$).

2) $M_S \cap M_A = \{0\}$ since $A = A^T = -A$ implies $2A = 0$ (again, this last $0$ is a matrix of zeroes).

3) If $A \in M_{2\times 2}$, then $A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$; the first term is in $M_S$ and the second is in $M_A$, so $M_{2\times 2} \subset M_S + M_A$. By (1) and (2) this means $M_{2\times 2} = M_S \oplus M_A$.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.